# Calculating expected ROAS (return on advertising spend) based on historical data

Tags: google-sheets, roi

I need to calculate what ROAS (return on advertising spend) I should have on days e.g. 7, 14, 28 after the launch of a campaign to get 120% on day 365. I have the spend and the revenue numbers readily available. I would like to use spreadsheets only if possible. I would appreciate any tips on how to approach this.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

**Calculation**
`ROAS = Revenue attributable to ads / Cost of ads`

**Formula**

```
=B9/B10
```

**Example**

[image]

> Create **Dropdown** to pick the date.

[image]

> And Use this formula to get **ROAS** in the chosen day *you can type the day.*

```
=INDEX(B12:12,1,MATCH(A14,B1:1,0))
```

[image]

> Getting **ROAS** Launch to date

```
=AVERAGE(B12:12)
```

[image]